# "Unexpected end of declaration" Android AIDE

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm following this [spinner_guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) to add a spinner to my app. I have added the following to MainActivity.java:

```
Spinner key_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.key_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> key_adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.spinner_keys,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
key_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
key_spinner.setAdapter(key_adapter);
```

with spinner_keys a string array defined in strings.xml and key_spinner is a spinner in main.xml. I get an unexpected end of declaration error at the brackets of the last two functions (the brackets are underlined with a red squiggly line in AIDE). I have had this error in another app I am working on but cannot see the cause. I have searched for the error term but have not found it. I suspect it may be due to the argument to the function not being recognised(?), but I don't really know - this (and the other mentioned app) are my first attempt at Android (and Java) programming.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing braces in your code. However, it is impossible to tell without the exact code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like this should be in a method body such as `onCreate()` and not in class body. In a class body the first two lines are valid since they define and initialize member variables, while the latter two lines are not valid in such context.

So, wrap the code in

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);

    // that code here

 }
```